# Spinner populated from firebase real-time database but doesn't retain value onItemSelected, it's reinitialized when re-entering activity

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-spinner

I have this code in an activity, it populates a spinner from a list stored in firebase real-time database. When I open this activity the initial value is '-None-' and when I make a selection in the spinner it sets the value correctly. My problem here is when I leave this activity and come back it selection is reinitialized back to None.

```
Query nanoQuery = mNanodegreesDatabase.orderByChild("nProgram");
    nanoQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            List<String> Nanodegrees = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (DataSnapshot nanoData : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String nanodegree = nanoData.child("nProgram").getValue(String.class);
                if (nanodegree != null) {
                    Nanodegrees.add(nanodegree);
                }
            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ProfileActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, Nanodegrees);
            arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            mSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

//<---- OnItem selection of at Nanodegree spinner ------------------------------------------>

```
mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String nanoD_selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        mUsersDatabase.child(mCurrentUserID).child("nanodegree").setValue(nanoD_selected);

        Log.w(TAG, "Nanodegree set to: " + nanoD_selected);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});
```

How do I make it to only respond when a selection is made or keep my selection when I exit the activity?

Comment: Post your full activity source code.

Comment: In the code you shared you **write** the item the user selects with `mUsersDatabase.child(mCurrentUserID).child("nanodegree").setValue(nanoD_selected)`. But none of the code you shared reads that value back and selects that item in the dropdown. The solution is to implement that part too.